# How to assign a value from a SELECT statement into a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to do this in my stored procedure:

```
declare @CategoryId int

-- stuff

IF EXISTS (select A_categoryId from dbo.categories
           where B_categoryId = @b_categoryId
           and C_cactegoryId = @c_categoryId
          )
          -- it doesn't like the following line:
          @CategoryId = select A_categoryId from dbo.categories
           where B_categoryId = @b_categoryId
           and C_cactegoryId = @c_categoryId
```

but it doesn't like the way it's structured. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT @CategoryId = A_categoryId from dbo.categories...`

That being said, please don't post questions about how to assign variables on SO.  This is really way below the scope of what the site is about and could have been resolved by reviewing any documentation for SQL Server.

Comment: If its a valid question that someone cannot answer I don't see why he / she cannot post a question like so.  If you don't want the question why did you post an answer to it?

Comment: @JonH - `Too Localized` I think pretty much covers it.  This question is pretty much guaranteed not to help anyone else in the future.

Comment: You'd be surprised - especially with TSQL.

Comment: Well had this question already been asked on SO, I wouldn't have asked it! And yes, I googled around for the correct syntax here, but the IF EXISTS examples I found didn't cover selecting into a variable, sorry. Anyways, I often find myself asking TSQL syntax questions because of the lack of documentation.

Comment: @JonH - I would be surprised if someone else had an issue with variable declaration and found it by searching for `IF EXISTS`, yes.

Comment: @JNK I think the title will be better now. Please check and change it if you think it needs.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for:

```
set @CategoryId = (select A_categoryId from dbo.categories
       where B_categoryId = @b_categoryId
       and C_cactegoryId = @c_categoryId)
```